# How to build a LME with nested random effects? A study with a very comlicated experimental design

Tags: lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, nested-data

I am trying to analyse the data on the climbing behaviour of flies. The design of the experiment was rather complicated, so I am currently struggling to build a propper LME model.

The flies have been tested in **3 tubes** (**10 flies per tube**) for 30 seconds (**300 frames**) 5 times (**5 trials**). This test was repeated 5 times (**5 blocks**) for **4 conditions** with **2 Exposures per condition** (Sham/Exposed) with different flies. Since we could not track single flies individually, I took the average position of 10 flies in tubes over time.

The total amount of biological replicates (tubes with different flies) was:
 **4 conditions * 2 Exposures * 5 blocks * 3 tubes = 120 individual tubes**

```
df$ID=interaction(df$cond, df$Exposure, df$tube, df$block)# provides unique ID for each individual tube
```

We want to check for an effect of Exposure*condition on the average climbing height (**Ycm**):

```
fixed = Ycm ~ cond*Exposure
```

The problem is with the random part of this model, since we have a lot of data, but most of them come from **pseudoreplicates of the same individuals: 5 trials * 300 frames**.
We decided not to use random intercept and slope model, because climbing is not linear. Instead we try to make an intercept model with nested random effects.

```
fly.lme = lmerTest::lmer(Ycm ~ Exposure*cond + (1|ID/trial/frame), data=df,na.action=na.exclude)
```

But this model gives an error message **Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations**.
It is a bit strange, because we have 15 independent tubes per Exposure*condition. To avoid this problem I tried to change the random structure of the model:

```
fly.lme.new = lmerTest::lmer(Ycm ~ Exposure*cond + (1|ID) + (1|trial/frame), data=df,na.action=na.exclude)
summary(fly.lme.new)

"Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: Ycm ~ Exposure * cond + (1 | ID) + (1 | trial/framecor)
   Data: cmaver

REML criterion at convergence: 592093.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-8.2787 -0.6177  0.0498  0.6695  8.0832 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 framecor:trial (Intercept) 17.7442  4.2124  
 ID             (Intercept)  0.7479  0.8648  
 trial          (Intercept)  0.1425  0.3774  
 Residual                    1.5627  1.2501  
Number of obs: 176742, groups:  frame:trial, 1505; ID, 120; trial, 5

Fixed effects:
                     Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          10.74801    0.30036  19.00000  35.784   <2e-16 ***
ExposureNMF          -0.34623    0.31601 111.99000  -1.096    0.276    
cond90               -0.10786    0.31601 111.99000  -0.341    0.734    
cond220               0.28570    0.31601 111.99000   0.904    0.368    
cond300               0.24126    0.31601 111.99000   0.763    0.447    
ExposureNMF:cond90    0.07384    0.44692 111.99000   0.165    0.869    
ExposureNMF:cond220  -0.14126    0.44691 111.99000  -0.316    0.753    
ExposureNMF:cond300   0.24407    0.44691 111.99000   0.546    0.586    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) ExpNMF cond90 cnd220 cnd300 ENMF:9 ENMF:2
ExposureNMF -0.526                                          
cond90      -0.526  0.500                                   
cond220     -0.526  0.500  0.500                            
cond300     -0.526  0.500  0.500  0.500                     
ExpsrNMF:90  0.372 -0.707 -0.707 -0.354 -0.354              
ExpsNMF:220  0.372 -0.707 -0.354 -0.707 -0.354  0.500       
ExpsNMF:300  0.372 -0.707 -0.354 -0.354 -0.707  0.500  0.500"

anova(fly.lme.new)
"Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
              Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value  Pr(>F)  
Exposure      5.7115  5.7115     1 111.99  3.6548 0.05846 .
cond          7.4426  2.4809     3 111.99  1.5875 0.19639  
Exposure:cond 1.2077  0.4026     3 111.99  0.2576 0.85577  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1"
```

This gives the expected outcome, but I wonder if this random structure is valid, because I thought that trials and frames should be also nested within individual tubes. Can I somehow check whether the DenDF of this model make sense or not?
I would really appreciate your opinion/suggestions.

Comment: (1) Are flies supposed to be climbing up during the 30 s? If so, treating `frame` as random effect does not make sense to me. Either average over frames if you want to ignore the time component. Or directly model time as a fixed effect with polynomial/spline terms or using GAMM. (2) The error message means that you have 1 data point per `ID:trial:frame` interaction which seems to be true, so no wonder. (3) Are shams in 4 conditions equivalent? If so, why not simply treat the data as having 5 different conditions (4 conditions + sham)?

Comment: @amoeba, (1) Most flies reach the top of the tube way before 30s, after that they could stay at the top or climb back and forth. Even worth, different fly lines climb with different speed, so that the average climbing curve looks rather different. So I don't want to completely ignore the time component, but it doesn't seem wise to me to include it as a fixed effect. (2) Ok, does it then mean that my second model with '(1|ID) + (1|trial/frame)' makes more sense?

Comment: @amoeba, (3) Yes, shams are generally equivalent, but there have been shams for each condition made simultaniously within the same block of tests. Since there is a substantial variation between blocks, I wouldn't pull all the shams together. Especially because I am also interested in the effect of "Exposure:condition" factor. Apart from it, it would unbalance the data, because then for 4 conditions I would have 15 tubes per condition, but for the sham-condition I would have 15*4=60 tubes.

Comment: Dear @BenBolker, probably you could have a look if you have time.